# How to get select box value with space in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

i want to get the dropdown value with space in javascript.I have used $('#loc').val() and document.getElementById("loc").value, but i got only one and three based on the below code.it is taking before space only.I want the answer like, one two and three four.

```
<form method="post" action="" name="xxx"> 
 <select name="loc" id="loc"> 
  <option value="one two">Choice 1</option> 
  <option value="three four">Choice 2</option> 
 </select> 
</form>
```

please share the answer for this? thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no element with id `loc` in your snippet. Anyway, it should work even with spaces in values.

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/uMr4R/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
   document.getElementsByName("choices")[0].value
```

**EDITED CODE**

```
<form method="post" action="" name="xxx"> 
 <select name="loc" id="loc" onchange="get_value()"> 
  <option value="one two">Choice 1</option> 
  <option value="three four">Choice 2</option> 
 </select> 
</form>

<script>
    function get_value(){
    alert(document.getElementsByName("loc")[0].value);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi rajesh, please share me any other idea.

Answer (score 0):

i have tested with the below code it works fine.it gives "one two" and "three four"

```
$(document).ready(function () {alert($("#sample").val());});

 function test() {
           alert($("#sample").val());
       }
 <select name="choices" id="sample" onchange="test()"> 
  <option value="one two">Choice 1</option> 
  <option value="three four">Choice 2</option> 
 </select>
```

Note: 
i tested with browser IE 8 
JS file referrd is jquery-1.8.2.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's `.val()` works fine.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uMr4R/1/

Comment: Actually i am checking in my android device,but still am not getting the answer.

Comment: try downloading a new browser to your android device, say google chrome latest version then try the same.